# Получение строки грида по попапу, открывающемуся при нажатии кнопки в этой строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть грид. В HTML он выглядит как таблица. В каждой строке в одной из колонок есть кнопка (например, "Добавить подробности"), при нажатии на которую открывается окно - попап.
Известен `id` этого попапа - например, `popup`.
Как узнать в какой строке мы нажали кнопку по `id` попапа?
Это нужно, чтобы в дальнейшем вытянуть одно из значений колонки строки.
Т.е. прописываем `$("#popup")`, а дальше?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку сохраняйте куда-либо необходимую информацию о строке, в которой находится данная кнопка, перед показом popup-a. Далее используйте эту информацию где вам нужно. Так как соответствующий код вы не предоставили, дальше абстрактного описания уйти не получится.

Comment: сформулирую вопрос по другому. Есть массив кнопок. Например узнал его так  - var buttons = $('.testButtons');  Как можно узнать какая из кнопок была нажата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О том, какая кнопка была нажата, можно понять по объекту события `e.target`:

```js
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#popup').html($(e.target).html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ячейка 1</td>
            <td>Ячейка 2</td>
            <td>Ячейка 3</td>
            <td>Ячейка 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="popup"></div>
```

вместо `e.target` в данном случае можно и просто `this` использовать, спасибо @Regent за правку

Comment: Umer,  спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Дмитрий вместо `e.target` можно и просто `this` использовать.